# On edit If Statement based on specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to use an onedit function that allows me to copy a row into another tab when a checkbox has been selected. I currently have a script that works on any edit but I am trying to make it so it will trigger only when the checkbox has been selected "value = true" in column A

this is the code I currently have but can not get the condition to work.

```
`function onEdit(e){
   const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  var checkboxtest = e.range.getValue()     
  if (src.getName() != "Form Responses" || r.columnStart != 1 || r.rowStart == 1 || checkboxtest == true) return;                           
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed CN");                                    
 src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,23).copyTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,23));                                 
 src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
```

}`

Tried applying my own code.

Answer (score 0):

e.value != "TRUE" fixed it for me!